# How do I get the name value from ngModel in the component

Tags: angular

Html looks like

```
<input #cntl (ngModelChange)="onModelChange(lastName,$event,#cntl) [(ngModel)]="lastName" #ctrl="ngModel" required>
```

In the component, I have

```
public onModelChange(oldValue,newValue,cntl){
    let bindingName=cntl.attributes("ngMogel"); //want to return lastName
}
```

The bindingName has null instead of lastName. How do I get lastName?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just pass a constant? `"onModelChange(lastName, $event, 'lastName')"`

Comment: Yes, that would work but I am trying to just pass the control as parameter and get any property value I need from it since this method in be added in multiple controls.